# Como obter posição(x, y) de Node inferior em BorderPane em relação à tela?

Tags: java, javafx, coordenadas

Tenho um BorderPane onde define seu valor bottom com um HBox:

```
borderPane.setBottom(new HBox(children));
```

Gostaria de saber a posição `(x,y)` principalmente a `y` do HBox em relação à tela.

Answer (score 2):

Achei a resposta no Stack em inglês:

```
Point2D bounds = borderPaneBottom.localToScene(borderPaneBottom.getLayoutBounds().getMinX(), borderPaneBottom.getLayoutBounds().getMinY());
```

Comment: Poderia incluir na sua resposta o link de onde achou a resposta?